# How to extract the encoded virtuemart Cart session data

Tags: virtuemart

I am using virtuemart 2.06 for joomla,
I have created a custom component to display some basic information regarding select payment type and  delivery time and user details, before displaying the user information i have to display the products added to the cart in the custom component view as review information of the purchased product to purchaser.

I have Printed the session data in the view page of custom component , but the session data of cart is encoded. How to extract the virtue mart cart sessiondata.

print_r($*SESSION['*_vm']['vmcart']);

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
print_r(unserialize($_SESSION['__vm']['vmcart']));
```

Comment: your answer is also very helpful to me. but when i am using your solution i am getting all data in one. now my question is how do i get that data separately eg. cart id, product id separately?